# ld exe in MINGW can not find library

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to build C++ code using MINGW 64 bit 4.8.0 and MSYS2.
I am using Windows 7 x64 with Netbeans 8.2 IDE.
I am getting below error while building the code

```
c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lldscripts
c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -l6to4svcl
```

I search the entire  MSYS/MINGW folder for these two library but I did not find any, is there any toolchain that need to be installed for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with Netbeans,  I switch to codeblocks and same code works.